# After 60 seconds on website, popup

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Well, i was trying to reach a solution and i thought this might work:

On the PHP file:

```
$liguem = getdate();

$liguemoff = $_COOKIE['liguemoff'];
$liguemon = $_COOKIE['liguemon'];

if(empty($liguemoff)){
    setcookie('liguemoff',$liguem[0],time() + (50000));
}

setcookie('liguemon',$liguem[0],time() + (20000));



$body->assign("COOKIE2", $liguemoff);
$body->assign("COOKIE3", $liguemon);
```

This has some body assign because I'm working with XTemplate, but the PHP is just PHP.

Now on the index file, some JavaScript:

```
var cookie2 = {COOKIE2};
var cookie3 = {COOKIE3};

if( cookie3-cookie2 > 60){
    alert('alerta');
};
```

Truth is that it works! People might not be navigating, but it is what i want, the pop up will only open after the visitor sees at least 2 pages  (Server-side thing).

The main problem is, that i CAN'T make the function `popup();` to trigger where i have the ALERT displaying. The ALERT is working alright though.... Any hints?

PS:

This is the `popthat();` function:

```
function popthat(){
    $("#darkside").css('opacity','0.3').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#darkside").click(function () { 
    $(this).css('opacity','1').fadeIn('fast');
    $("#liguem").hide();
    });
        $("#liguem").corner();
    $("#liguem").hide();
    $("#liguem").delay(200).css('visibility','visible');
    $("#liguem").fadeIn('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a timeout to display your popup after a specified amount of time. This amount of time can be dicated by your PHP since the server-side code will be able to track the amount of time on the site through page-views. This way the popup can display after 60 seconds on the site even if the user is not navigating to another page.

Something like:

```
setTimeout(popthat, <?php echo $_COOKIE[...]; ?>);
```

Your PHP would echo the number of milliseconds until the popup should display.

A note: when you replace your `alert()` with the `popthat()` function the DOM may not be ready and `popthat()` won't be able to work because it won't find any elements that match your selectors. Try running your code on `document.ready` (`$(function() {});`).

Answer (score 0):

Browsers automatically block popups initialized on page load, because nobody likes these sorts of popups.

Comment: I will add more info for you to see the popup. It's jquery made, not a real pop up

Comment: You didn't think that might be relevant info?

Comment: You mean it's a floating div overlay, not a window.open() type thing?

Comment: @ceejayoz As a matter of fact, it's not important, because i can't trigger any kind of function inside the if statement. I think this never happened before... If the popup got blocked, i would perceive the warning the browser gives.

Comment: @Marc B, yep, you're correct. But the popup is working very well.

Comment: @Souza: then check your JS console (shift-ctrl-J in FF/Chrome) to see if something's blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an `alert()`, execution of your script stops.  `alert()` is a blocking function, and nothing will happen until it has moved on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you just made a typo, but your function is called popthat(), and in your statement you said you called the function popup(). You need to change popup(); to popthat(); for this to work, unless as I said that was a mistake.